# Flight cancelled by Ryanair 16 May 2020. Refund requested

Tags: bookings, covid-19, refunds, ryanair

Ryanair cancelled my return flight to Palma (outward 22/06/2020 FR9997 and return 29/06/20202 FR 9998) on 16/05/2020. On the option of getting a refund or a voucher, I opted for the full refund as I wasn't sure when I might get to travel. I requested the refund on the foot of the cancellation details on 16/05/2020 to which I got back a reply (on the same date at 15.26) thanking me for my refund application and adding the statement:

> Once approved your refund request will be processed within 20 working days to the original form of payment and should show in your account within the next 5 - 7 working days. A confirmation email will be sent to the address provided in your booking.

I have neither received the refund nor got an email. I have a screen shot of the flight cancellation information received on the 16/05/2020 and the  acknowledgement of my full refund received on the the 16/05/2020.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Firstly, best not to include personal details in a question. Secondly, have you contacted Ryanair to follow this up? And/or contacted your bank/credit card issuer?

Comment: In a word, chargeback.

Answer (score 3):

Send a screenshot of the auto-reply to your request (with the date visible) as well as the original booking receipt and the cancellation confirmation to your bank, and file a dispute against the purchase of the ticket. This way you'll get the money back.

Comment: Actually, first call your bank. Ask for a chargeback, then you will receive some documents in the mail asking for more information. That's when you should include a copy of your screenshot. They will also want to know many times you tried contacting Ryanair, so keep a log.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Varies from bank to bank. None of my banks has ever expected me to call first. One accepts a plain e-mail, two others wants me to email a signed scanned form

Comment: Many banks have a "time out" for chargebacks. It's often 90 days, so that ship might have sailed.

Comment: @Hilmar Now during COVID-19 you're expected to be more patient, so I'd expect some leeway with this. Even before the pandemic, my banks have never been bitches about it (YMMV)